# How do I use grep for returning the bool value of this variable?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, boolean

I want stout to return the bool value of the "standby" variable in:

```
pmset -g | grep standby
```

The output, obviously here is:

```
standbydelay         10800
 standby              0 #<--This is what I want!#
```

Additionally:

```
pmset -g | grep -cim1 standby
```

Returns `1` meaning only the string exists. It gives me no information regarding it's bool value though.

**What's the syntax for printing the bool value "0" to stout?** I suspect an additional argument is needed using `awk` or `print`, but I do not know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will a simple

```
$ ... | awk '/ standby/{print $2}'
0
```

do the job?

Comment: +1. You could also narrow it down a bit by using `$1 == "standby" { print $2}`

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with Fredrik Pihl's suggestion. However, you can also take advantage of grep's exit code:

```
if grep -q 'standby  *1' file
then
  echo "It's set to 1"
else
  echo "It's either set to 0 or not present"
fi
```

Comment: Interactive commands are not limited to one line, so you can type/paste this exactly as written with linefeeds and all. If you want it in a single line, `if grep -q 'standby  *1' file; then echo "foo"; else echo "bar"; fi`

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed`:

```
$ com () { echo "standbydelay         10800
 standby              0"; }
$ com | sed -n 's/ standby[[:space:]]\+//p'
0
```